# mysql events with specific time

Tags: mysql, function, time, storage

I'm using mysql from a hosting company. They give me 50 mb max storage for mysql. And There is a table which grows very fast in my mysql. If I save this table in different format to my server and clean my table for new entries I don't have any storage problems.

My question is, is there a way to set a timeout for server to do it? I mean like if there is a way from server to start a function on a specific time.

Let's say I want my server to start a function at 01.15.2012.. Can I do that? Like is there a way to set server to start my function? and can I write a php function to save my mysql table and clean it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Linux server you can use [cron](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html). Write your php script, then set up the cron process to execute the script at a particular time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm working with a hosting company, can you tell me how can I set up the cron? Or can you give me a basic tutorial for installing the cron to my host. Because I'm searching more information about cron but all I can found is how to use it, not how to set it up.. I don't even know if my hosting supports cron or if I have privileges. Can you tell me how to test it?

Comment: How to set it up will depend on your host. Do they have any documentation on using cron?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) to run a script or to call stored function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I just made a research about MySQL events and I learned I'm not able to do it because of the privileges. When I tried some commands it says that I need SUPER privilege.

Comment: May you ask administrator or someone else who has SUPER privilege to create the event?